# Copiar tudo antes da primeira linha em branco

Tags: linux, shell-script, perl, awk

Eu tenho um arquivo com vários blocos de texto, separados por linha em branco. Ex.:

bloco1
bloco1

bloco2

bloco3
bloco3

Preciso de uma solução com sed, awk ou perl que localize a primeira linha em branco e redirecione o bloco anterior a ela para outro arquivo e assim sucessivamente a até o final do arquivo.

Tenho este comando em sed que localiza o primeiro bloco, mas não o restante: sed -e '/./!Q'

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

O seguinte comando cria ficheiros "output1", "output2", etc., com cada bloco.

```
awk -v RS="" '{print > "output" NR }' input.txt
```

Explicação:

- `RS=""`  registos separados por uma ou mais linhas em branco
- `print > "output" NR` escreve o bloco em output+número do registo.

Era isto o que pretendes?

Comment: Exato João, isto é o que precisava. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi certo, mas se seu objetivo é remover as linhas em branco, pode usar o seguinte comando:

```
sed '/^\s*$/d'
```

Comment: Renato, eu preciso localizar a linha em branco e mover tudo que vem antes dela para outro arquivo, não deleta-la.

Comment: Só do primeiro bloco? Ou VC quer integrar pelo arquivo e gerar vários arquivos ?

Comment: Preciso gerar vários aquivos, um para cada bloco existente no arquivo base.